# creating translations - painless

Tags: c, linux, translation, xgettext

The current way I create translation catalogs and manage translations is:

1. generate headers from all non source code file types (glade, .desktop, ...) via `intltool`
2. use `xgettext` to gather all strings from all `*.[ch]` files and generata a `.pot`
3. do `msgmerge` for existing `.po` files

**Is there a tool that can handle all 3 tasks without having to generate intermediate files?**

Note: I've been looking for that kind of tool for a long time but never really found one, so I apologize if the answer is trivial.

Comment: maybe the solution you are looking for does not yet exist. I'd love to see some good solutions for this particular problem!

Comment: AFAIK, `autotools` integration of `gettext` does it more or less automatically.

Comment: @rodrigo I am not going to switch a complete, convenient and nicely working build environment because of inconvenient translations. Also autotools would introduce itself a gigaton of intermediate files - no thanks.